# Can I put value in stub.returnsThis() when substituting method during test?

Tags: node.js, express, mocking, sinon

If I have some class:

```js
class ServiceClient {

  setVaultClient(vaultClient) {
        this.vaultClientObj = vaultClient;
    }
  
}
```

and I want to mock the result of this method (means I want `this.vaultClientObj` to be what I say, but not the real one) - how can I do that? I am trying with stub.returnsThis() and I wonder if I can put some specific value - not just to be returned `this`, but to be returned `this.vaultClientObj` value that i want.

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example